# Weird pixelated checkerboard when installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I recently tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my new computer, I tried the windows installer and from a CD but both have failed. As soon as I try to reboot my PC and install it this weird colorful, pixelated checkerboard fills the screen and soon after my monitors loses the signal. I tried following some fixes but they all needed the terminal which I couldn't access. 
My computer specs are:

- Intel i5-2320 3.0Ghz
- 8GB Ram
- AMD Radeon HD 6670 2GB GDDR3

I use dual monitors but I tried the installation with and without both plugged in.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot through grub into the advanced mode and recovery mode.  Once the recovery window pops up, select resume.

If this works, check out grub start option `nomodeset` for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and update afterwards with

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with your reply. I have looked in the installation folder for an option to boot through grub but there's nothing. I've checked in C:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub and C:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub but cant seem to find anything, thanks again for the help.